# Flatten array with index into object with types

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can someone help me flatten this array into the desired format? I can't figure it out. I need the parent key to have a name of "type" and the subparent key to having a value of "category".

May be best to put it into beautify so you can see the format better. Couldn't seem to do it here...

```
[{
    "Labour": {
      "Cleaners": {
        "unitCost": 3409.5,
        "markupValue": 18,
        "totalCost": 3643.5
      },
      "Plumber": {
        "unitCost": 309.0909,
        "markupValue": 0,
        "totalCost": 309.0909
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Material": {
      "Cleaners": {
        "unitCost": 450,
        "markupValue": 5,
        "totalCost": 475
      },
      "Plumber": {
        "unitCost": 450,
        "markupValue": 5,
        "totalCost": 475
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Other": {
      "Report Fee": {
        "unitCost": 180,
        "markupValue": 0,
        "totalCost": 180
      }
    }
  }
]

[{
    "type": "Labour",
    "category": "Cleaners",
    "unitCost": 3409.5,
    "markupValue": 18,
    "totalCost": 3643.5
  },
  {
    "type": "Labour",
    "category": "Plumbers",
    "unitCost": 3409.5,
    "markupValue": 18,
    "totalCost": 3643.5
  },
  {
    "type": "Material",
    "category": "Cleaners",
    "unitCost": 450.5,
    "markupValue": 0,
    "totalCost": 5
  },
  {
    "type": "Material",
    "category": "Plumbers",
    "unitCost": 450.5,
    "markupValue": 0,
    "totalCost": 5
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array.prototype.flatMap()` and `Array.prototype.flat()` functions, you can convert multi-dimensional arrays to 1d array as follow.

```js
const input = [
  {
    "Labour": {
      "Cleaners": {
        "unitCost": 3409.5,
        "markupValue": 18,
        "totalCost": 3643.5
      },
      "Plumber": {
        "unitCost": 309.0909,
        "markupValue": 0,
        "totalCost": 309.0909
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Material": {
      "Cleaners": {
        "unitCost": 450,
        "markupValue": 5,
        "totalCost": 475
      },
      "Plumber": {
        "unitCost": 450,
        "markupValue": 5,
        "totalCost": 475
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Other": {
      "Report Fee": {
        "unitCost": 180,
        "markupValue": 0,
        "totalCost": 180
      }
    }
  }
];

const output = input.flatMap((item) => {
  return Object.entries(item).map(([type, value]) => (Object.entries(value)
    .map(([category, subValue]) => ({
      type,
      category,
      ...subValue
    }))
  ));
}).flat();
console.log(output);
```